# checkbox text showing below checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

In my web application(visual studio 2010), check-box is not showing it's text on the same line.
please help me. I am attaching a sample image with this.!

[image]

Comment: display code in fiddler...

Comment: Maybe that's the problem with your's layout

Comment: increase the width of checkbox..

Comment: and VS2010 has **what** to do with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

html

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkNotify" Text="Name"
            runat="server" 
            CssClass="checkboxlist_nowrap"
            RepeatLayout="Table" 
            />
```

and css style

```
.checkboxlist_nowrap label
{
     display:inline;
}
```

Comment: great.. your code works superb